# Does the API provide language code of the transcription?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm planning to transcribe a speech where the language is unknown, so I am trying to detect the language spoken automatically with multiple language codes given, however, I can't seem to find an option to actually find out which language the transcription will be in.

I've looked through the dev page of the speech-to-text api, but I can't seem to find a way to output the language code of the transcribed text.

Anyone could help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the language code is returned with the results. For example, see the [sample code here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-languages#using_a_local_file), which shows how to retrieve the language code from the results.

However, see the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52852166/6952495). The language code does not always get returned when multiple languages are specified. As reported in the comments, this is an issue with the Google Speech API, an issue which reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117917739).